# Labelling random point with it's constraining feature name

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I was wondering if after a random point creation and constraining it to a feature class (with several features). Can I add a field (to the output table) which displays (names) the correlating feature the point was constrained to? I am assuming since the point was constrained to a feature, that information is available somewhere - though I might be completely off on this assumption.

For example, I create 5 random points in a feature class that has 5 features (5 polygons). In the output, am I able to indicate/label in a new field each random's constraining polygon?

Comment: Use tool Spatial Join

Answer (score 1):

As BERA suggested, use Spatial Join. You can use the [geoprocessing tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm), or in this simple case, you can just follow the step-by-step spatial join instructions ESRI has [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/finding-what-intersects-a-feature.htm). Right click on your *points* and join polygons to points. The points will pick up the attributes of the polygon that it falls inside.